# How do I declare "Key" fields in C# anonymous types?

Tags: c#, vb.net, anonymous-types

In VB.NET I'm used to doing things like this when creating anonymous types ([VB.NET anonymous types include the notion of Key Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx)):

```
Dim prod1 = New With {
    Key .Name = "paperclips",
    Key .Price = 1.29,
    .OnHand = 423
}
```

However, I haven't been able to find any way of doing this in C#, since it appears the `Key` keyword is not supported.

Is there any way to indicate in C# that I only want to compare some of the fields in anonymous type when looking for equality?

Comment: I'm always amazed by the little differences between C# and VB. I certainly didn't know you could do this is VB.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is nothing like that in C#. [In C#, all properties of anonymous types are read-only and participate in equality comparisons.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types)

If you want to do something like this in C#, you will need to create your own (named) type.

Comment: To expand a little: MSDN says that the automagically generated `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations use every property of the anonymous type. They use each type of the properties to call their implementations of `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Comment: It's a shame such a handy feature doesn't exist in C#.  It's probably not worth much, but I created a [suggestion](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3572724-c-feature-request-key-fields-in-anonymous-type) on the uservoice forums for a feature request.

Comment: Does this mean that, effectively, every property of an anonymous type in C# is the same as a VB.NET Key property?

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin Yeah, it does. In both cases, they are read-only and used in equality comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

There is no Key equivalent in c#.