# Split a List into parts - VB conversion fails

Tags: .net, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

Trying to write a method that splits a list into sublists.

```
Private Function SplitIdsIntoChunks(ByVal keys As List(Of String)) As List(Of List(Of String))
    Return keys _
        .Select(Function(x, i) New With {Key .Index = i, Key .Value = x}) _
        .GroupBy(Function(x) (x.Index / 10000)) _
        .Select(Function(x) x.Select(Function(v) v.Value).ToList()) _
        .ToList()
End Function
```

I used C# solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq).
C# solution works fine.

My version written in VB returns a collection of lists with one element instead of 10000.
Where did I go wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:**

Usage:

```
Dim chunks As List(Of List(Of String)) = SplitIdsIntoChunks(keys)
```

'Keys' content:

[image]

My method returns a lists of lists with one item inside:

[image]

Expected result: list of two lists - 10000 items in first and 6256 in second.

Comment: Even though it probably wouldn't be necessary for someone to answer your question in this case, are you able to post what you did in VB.NET?  I'm mainly just saying it since you already mentioned a specific error you've run into, so it might decorate the question just a little bit to add that in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split a collection into n parts with LINQ, in VB.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847591/split-a-collection-into-n-parts-with-linq-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main 'problem' is that in c# dividing an int by an int, `x.Index / 3`, results in an integer.  Standard division `/` in VB always results in a `Double` and therefore a unique Group for each item. e.g.: {.33, .333333, .333334} etc.

The 'trick' is to use integer division `\` to get an integer result. I also added a `chunksize` argument to make it more flexible and reusable:

```
Private Function SplitIntoChunks(keys As List(Of String), chunkSize As Integer) As List(Of List(Of String))
    Return keys.
            Select(Function(x, i) New With {Key .Index = i, Key .Value = x}).
            GroupBy(Function(x) (x.Index \ chunkSize)).
            Select(Function(x) x.Select(Function(v) v.Value).ToList()).
            ToList()
End Function
```

One other difference is that `c#` is very flexible regarding line continuation, so the dot can be at the start or end of a line.  VB (since VS2010) supports implicit line continuation *after* a great many things including member qualifier character (the dot `.`) so you can get rid of the explicit line continuation (`" _"`).

Usage:

```
' split list of 1000 into 300 chunks
Dim splits = SplitIntoChunks(myList, 300)

For n As Integer = 0 To splits.Count - 1
    Console.WriteLine("Split {0} has {1} items", n.ToString(), splits(n).Count)
Next
```

Output/Result:

> Split 0 has 300 items
>   Split 1 has 300 items
>   Split 2 has 300 items
>   Splits 3 has 100 items

Note that there is a lot of commentary on the linked C# post about performance of various methods.  This just gets it working, some of the alternatives might perform better depending on what is actually being split.  The [`Skip` and `Take` approach used here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28848677/1070452) is interesting too.

Answer (score 2):

The correct translation of that code is:

```
Private Function SplitIdsIntoChunks(ByVal keys As List(Of String)) As List(Of List(Of String))
    Return keys _
        .Select(Function(x, i) New With {Key .Index = i, Key .Value = x}) _
        .GroupBy(Function(x) (x.Index \ 10000)) _
        .Select(Function(x) x.Select(Function(v) v.Value).ToList()) _
        .ToList()
End Function
```

Note the difference between [`/`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25bswc76.aspx) (which returns a  floating-point) and [`\`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0e16fywh.aspx) (which returns an integer).

Answer (score -1):

In the linked answer the First Select is like this

```
.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
```

You have in your code

```
.Select(Function(x, i) New With {Key .Index = i, Key .Value = x})
```

Why did you repeat Key, I think you only need to specify the Properties of the anonymous type

Comment: From this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14431601/945456) is sounds like maybe every property in C# is `Key`? Looks like there's some variation between VB and C# in this area.

Comment: The C# code creates an anonymous type with two properties Index and Value, why do you need Key in the VB code.   Doesn't work? can you post the code you use and the error message please.  You shouldn't need any Key in the VB code

Comment: `New With {Key .Index = i, Key .Value = x}` creates an anonymous type with two properties `Index` and `Value`. It's actually good practise to always use the `Key` keyword when working with anonymous types, since it makes it easier to reason how the type behaves.

Comment: I never had to use that in VB Code...I've always used
new With { .PropA = x, .PropB = y} which is like in C# new {PropA = x, PropB = y}.  I don't see why I need the Key [keyword] in there.  Can someone explain or redirect my search to understand this

Comment: For an example, take a look at this question: [Identical (?) C# and VB.NET LINQ queries return different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928214/identical-c-sharp-and-vb-net-linq-queries-return-different-results)

Comment: Thanks a million, I had no clue about that,  very helpful of you!